# How to combine arrays which are in the dimensionel array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to combine "n" number of arrays that which are in the dimensionel array..

Something like;

Dimensionel array;

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:52 [▶]
  1 => array:5 [▶]
  ...
  n => array:2 [▶]
]
```

I want to do that;

```
  array:1 [▼
      0 => array: x[▶]
      ]
```

How can I do that ?

(I searched in here and in the doc but I can't find anything about it. They all talking about merge two different dimensional arrays.. So here I am..)

Comment: Explaind well what you want

Comment: 52 + 5 + + n + 2 = x :)

Comment: `$result[] = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);`

Comment: @AbraCadaver its working, thank you. You can add as answer if you want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`call_user_func_array` will take your array as an array of arguments and pass to `array_merge`.  I added the `[]` to add an additional dimension to the result to match the output you show:

```
$result[] = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```